# What is the "puerto rican mambo" in cuban salsa?

Tags: latin-jazz, dance

Good evening!

I took a lecture of salsa this year and I was wondering, what is the dance movement like in the Cuban salsa style called "Puerto Rican mambo"? (This is not about Puerto Rican salsa.)

I've searched the internet for finding such information, some videos or photos... nothing...

Comment: 'Puerto Rican Mambo' is definitely not a common style within Cuban salsa. Where did you see this mentioned? The author might have been referring to a mambo section played in the style of Puerto Rican bands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "mambo puertorriqueño" and found http://www.mamboenclave.com/en/articulos/?ide=8 which says

> ... el dos refleja el estilo puertorriqueño de tocar las acongas o tumbadoras, porque éste enfatiza el dos más que en, por ejemplo, el estilo cubano.

Translating,

> ...the "on 2" reflects the Puerto Rican style of playing the conga drums, because this style emphasizes the "2" [beat 2] more than, for example, the Cuban style.